# HTTPS Post request in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, ionic3, aws-lambda

I'm working on an Ionic 3 application which requires me to send encrypted data over internet to AWS lambda function. I have a API created for this lambda function and I'm able to send a post request to the lambda function using ionic's [http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) plugin. But we can easily track the post requests send from the current configuration of my application in the Network logs.

So how can I send my data from app to AWS lambda function in a secured way?

I read about the [SSLpinning](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#enableSSLPinning) in http plugin but is this the only way to approach the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with encrypting in the app is, that it's not that hard to make reverse enginering to see how it is made. 
It's a little harder to crack if you get a key from the server at login (or daily) and use this for encrypting.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/aes256/
I am pretty sure you can find other pre-made modules. Else make your own. Hackers hate custom design. 
And btw - https-communication to be sure it's actual is you the app is talking to.

Comment: to get the key from server, I'll still have to make sure that the connection is secured right? which is the whole purpose of the question. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right - deadlock - in Danish we ask: _Who came first: the ckicken or the egg._

Comment: so is there a way to approach it?

Comment: Probably your server and db are more in danger so better focus on the right spots. So encryption + https + only saved sanded hash for password,  is my current "level"